# Does this void the MVC design pattern?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I am wondering if having a local Student(Model) pulled through using a controller to my view class voids the MVC design pattern.

F.Y.I

I never import my Student model into the view class.

---

Controller

```
public void saveStudent(int selectedRow, Student studentChanged){
    studentList.getStudentList().set(selectedRow, studentChanged);
}
```

View

```
Student currentStudent;
```

.
.
.
.

```
public StudentDetailedUI(StudentCntrl studentCntrIn, int selectedRowIn) {
    studentCntrl = studentCntrIn;
    selectedRow = selectedRowIn;
    if (selectedRow >= 0) {
        currentStudent = studentCntrl.getStudent(selectedRow);
        initComponents();
        parseCurrentStudent();
    } else {
        initComponents();
        parseNewStudent();
    }
}
```

.
.
.
.

```
JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");
    saveButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        if (selectedRow != -1){
            currentStudent.setFirstName(firstNameDisplayValue.getText());
            currentStudent.setLastName(lastNameDisplayValue.getText());
            currentStudent.setUniversity(universityDisplayValue.getText());
            currentStudent.setGpa(Double.parseDouble(gpaDisplayValue.getText()));
            StudentDetailedUI.this.studentCntrl.saveStudent(selectedRow, currentStudent);
            StudentDetailedUI.this.studentCntrl.getStudentListUI();
        }
        else {
            StudentDetailedUI.this.studentCntrl.addStudent(firstNameDisplayValue.getText() +", " +lastNameDisplayValue.getText() +", " +universityDisplayValue.getText() +", " +gpaDisplayValue.getText());
            StudentDetailedUI.this.studentCntrl.getStudentListUI();
        }
    });
```

---

My intended functionality is to update an existing student in a list using a list-detail GUI.

Comment: TL;DR: It doesn't matter if it does or doesn't, and "MVC" means different things in different frameworks and to different people. How else would you get data into the view?

Comment: I could convert it into a string as it is being pulled from the controller. Then send the edited string to the controller and then parse the string into a student model. However I feel its a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: That's still passing a model, just happens to be serialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ok as long all the logic regarding the update remains in the controller, eventually you can add some validation in the view, but still the controller should have the last word on contacting the persistence layer.